# Insert Razor text into string from Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Can anyone help me with some Razor syntax?
I have a foreach loop ( shown at the end) and I would like to insert two items of text into a link to produce something like this:

```
<a href="/PDFFiles/Dummy.pdf#page=123" target="_blank">
```

I hope my question is clear,
Many thanks.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
  {
    <a href="/PDFFiles/**item.Filename**.pdf#page=**item.PageNum**" target="_blank">
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <a href="@Html.AttributeEncode(@Url.Content("~/PDFFiles/" + item.Filename + ".pdf#page=" + item.PageNum))" target="_blank">Download</a>
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just prefix your variable name with `@`

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  <a href="/PDFFiles/@(item.Filename).pdf#page=@(item.PageNum)" target="_blank">
}
```